# ScotchBox 2.5 Used With CakePHP

Tags: vagrant, lamp

I'm trying to get away from Xampp and use Vagrant.  I attempted to create a shell provisioned LAMP, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.

How would you alter ScotchBox to point a vhost at test.dev at `/app/webroot` instead of it being in `/public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/public` is just the directory under the site and `var/www` so the web server just reads from the directory - if you want to point at `/app/webroot` just create this directory under `/var/www` and all sites directory, it should work just fine

You can also check from the doc at https://scotch.io/bar-talk/announcing-scotch-box-2-0-our-dead-simple-vagrant-lamp-stack-improved#changing-/public-to-/public_html with an example to change `/public` to `/public_html` with a provision script to make the change on the directory at provision time